# Threading: Why does this code show 5 in output in thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a simple code which has a lock and creates 5 threads.

```
static readonly object _object = new object();

static void A(int currentValue)
{
    lock (_object)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(currentValue + " Start");                
        Console.WriteLine(currentValue + " End");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => A(i));
        t.Name = "Thread " + i;
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name + " Created");
        t.Start();                
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I run this code, the following is displayed in the output.

```
Thread 0 Created
Thread 1 Created
1 Start
1 End
Thread 2 Created
2 Start
2 End
Thread 3 Created
3 Start
3 End
Thread 4 Created
4 Start
4 End
5 Start
5 End
```

When I am only creating 5 threads (0 - 4). Why do I see an entry for 5 Start and 5 End?

Comment: Try pre increment instead of post increment e.g. ++i

Comment: I'm not sure of the root cause, but I imagine these are related:  I notice that you don't have '0 Start' and '0 End' lines.  It looks like the i is getting incremented before each thread runs, but is still the same i for the 'thread created' line.  My best guess is that when the thread runs, it takes the latest value of i, rather than the value for i at the time you declare the thread variable.  Are you consistently getting the same results?

(See also Peter Duniho's answer - very relevant)

Comment: The problem is that the variable `i` has changed by the time the thread is started. You are lucky that any thread even gets to start before the entire loop has completed. Normally, when you write a bug like this, the behavior is that _all_ of the threads print `5`. See marked duplicate (Lasse's answer) for details on fixing it.

Comment: More importantly, the described behaviour will remain regardless of the `lock` statement being present in the code, so the question is - *why* is there a `lock` statement?

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy It stops two threads calling `Console` methods at the same time and interleaving the two calls (or even interleaving characters written within one call, which I believe can happen).

Comment: @Rawling that is true, but then Kaveesh is left with a scrambled  for loop output, without the advantage of parallel processing

Comment: @MongZhu I suspect in the real world `A` would be doing some parallelizable work before finally locking in order to write to `Console`, or add output to a collection, or do something else not-thread-safe.

Comment: @Rawling I guess you`re right. Just in this context one ends up with a scrambled for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when a thread is started and the call of `A` happpens the compiler will jump for a brief moment into this line go to get the parameter:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => A(i));
```

if at this point in time the loop is already finished the variable `i` will have a value of 5. So it will take this value. This phenomenon is called closure I guess. Here is the article [The Beauty of Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

You can get out of it if you save the `i` value into a newly declared temporal variable like this and the 5 will not come upt anymore

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int temp = i;
    Thread t = new Thread(() => A(temp));
    t.Name = "Thread " + i;
    t.Start();
}
```

Here is an [answer to a very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271447/5174469)

The `lock` is actually not necessary in this context since you access only local variables in the method `A`. Every thread will have its own personal variable. The lock actually inhibits the threads to run in parallel. Unless you wanted it this way but then you don't need threads.